# gparted with Jammy Jellyfish 22.04 error message

Tags: gparted, 22.04

Gparted shows up in the applications menu, but on launching I get the message

(gpartedbin:41715): Gtk WARNING **: 18:10:36:20: cannot open display:

where 18:10:36:20 was the time of the message.

Then, gparted's GUI window doesn't open.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing gparted.  This did at least make gparted appear on the applications screen.

Gparted worked fine under 20.04.

Comment: How are you launching GParted? And are you in the default Wayland or X?

Comment: I tried opening it just by typing 'gparted' in Terminal - that's how I got the error message.  If I click on the application, an icon appears on the dock bar and then immediately vanishes.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your installation. I can't reproduce the error. Just as an experiment try `sudo gparted`... And, again, Wayland or X? Or have you installed something other than the default Gnome desktop environment?

Comment: sudo gparted works.  Thanks!  I have installed the default Gnome desktop environment, I don't know what this is called.

Comment: "Vanilla" Ubuntu comes with Gnome already. Other flavors (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.) come with other DEs. If you installed something Gnome related on top then that's likely the cause of the problem. Also if running it with `sudo` works it suggests there's something else very wrong. GParted is supposed to ask for root authentication by itself.

Comment: It's 'vanilla' ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish 22.04 LTE.  Before I had 'vanilla' 20.04 LTE and it worked fine.  All I have done is install 22.04 LTE in place of 20.04.  However, I now have a workaround and I'm happy with the solution you have provided.